# Why do I get `missing proxy for identifier <some external object>` messages?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have an app with a tab bar controller which supervises two view controllers, each with it's own nib.  Each nib has some external objects (the view controller in each case, plus some singletons in the other case).  When this thing launches, I get messages in the console which say "missing proxy for identifier" followed by the name of one of the external objects.  It looks to me like this is just a message as the app seems to run fine.  The nib and objects all seem to be hooked up fine.

My question: is this message a problem, and if so, what is it trying to tell me?  I feel like it may mean something is not hooked up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the following

you are using two rows in a table with same reusable identifier in a tableView or table view controller

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it might be due to some kind of conflict with a previous version if the app being installed, my problem was solved after deleting the app a reinstalling it.